# Facebook Chat in Node

Tags: node.js, facebook-chat

So the situation is this: i'm able to authenticate and get/send messages with one fb account, with other two authentication is failing. It should work for all accounts, or not work at all and i'm not able to find the answer of this strange thing. What i'm missing?

Steps:

1. Using example app: https://github.com/Takeno/node-facebookchat
2. Through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ version 1 getting accessToken (selecting all permissions just in case).
3. Writing all the info into example/index.js: appId, secretId, userId and the accessToken.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have start the Submission-Process?

If you create a App first you are the only FB-User how can use it. Until facebook haven't review your app is only for your facebook-account.